# the content of struct SBGestureContextRef

Tags: ios, jailbreak, springboard

I have hooked SBGestureRecognizer by mobilesubstate.

But I want to know the content of SBGestureContextRef, helping me to analyze the touch in SpringBoard.

The struct SBGestureContextRef is used by these functions:

```
-(void)touchesCancelled:(SBGestureContextRef)arg1;
-(void)touchesEnded:(SBGestureContextRef)arg1;
-(void)touchesMoved:(SBGestureContextRef)arg1;
-(void)touchesBegan:(SBGestureContextRef)arg1;
```

Could anyone help me ?